# How to search and replace a decimal value in directory of CSVs?

Tags: regex, csv, replace, terminal, grep

I have directory of CSVs which looks like this

```
1234,abc,234-kladf-32lk,23,alkdf,2019-10-29:00:00:00,Word,0.02,word,23,abc,adk
```

or like this

```
1234,abc,234-kladf-32lk,23,alkdf,2019-10-29:00:00:00,Word,0.01,123,23,abc,adk
```

the difference being a word or number after the decimal.

I want to replace the decimal value with the same value and another column, e.g

```
,0.02, -> ,0.02,new_value,
```

All the new values will be the same, but the decimal values can vary. I'm having a bit of difficulty with this because of the period in the decimal..it's throwing off my regex. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can a decimal appear anywhere else? Are you only interested in the data from the 8th column? Is the 8th column ever not a decimal? Is `1234,abc,234-kladf-32lk,23,alkdf,2019-10-29:00:00:00,"Literal, comma, 1.2,",0.01,123,23,abc,adk` possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this expression

```
([0-9]\.[0-9]+\s*,)
```

with a replacement of `$1new_value,` might simply work.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IK7LZX/1/)